# Windows.h behaves different in windows form C++

Tags: c++

I made some code in an empty project (visual studio) it uses Windows.h
i want to put this program inside my c++ windows form application.
so i made a class for it. odd thing is the code gives me an error

```
#include "ImageCompiler.h"



ImageCompiler::ImageCompiler()
{
}

void ImageCompiler::find_images()
{

}

std::vector<string> ImageCompiler::get_all_files_names_within_folder(string folder)
{
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::string search_path = folder + "/*.*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(search_path.c_str(), &fd);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            if (!(fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
                names.push_back(fd.cFileName);
            }
        } while (::FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));
        ::FindClose(hFind);
    }
    return names;
}
```

it says that search_path (const char *) does not match argument (LPCWSTR)
there is nothing special in the header file (only #include Windows.h)
and some other class things.

if i create a empty program with just windows.h and this code it will work.
but not in the windows form application even when its in another file and 
they don't include each other. i don't understand this. 
i'm actually really stupid and bad in programming so its probably a stupid
mistake. i hope someone can help me. i can give you the code from the 
Myform.h but i don't think that will help.

Comment: UNICODE is always #defined in a C++/CLI app.  Use std::wstring or FindFirstFileA() or System::IO::Directory::GetFiles()

Comment: If you are using  .Net, you should probably avoid using the Win API directly in any case.

Comment: .Net? win API i don't know anything about both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in windows.h the type strings and string pointer type aliases are defined according to whether or not you are building with or without Unicode support.  In this case the W (for wide) in LPCWSTR indicates Unicode build, so `char*` interfaces are not compatible.

The simplest solution if you don't need it is to switch off Unicode/wide-character string support for the build.  I sm not sure however if that is possible for C++/CLI, in which case use 'wchar` interfaces where necessary.

An empty project including windows.h compiles simply because you will not have *used* any interfaces.  If there is no code, there is no attempt to assign incompatible types, so no error.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, if you're using Managed C++ (C++/CLI), use it as much as possible. [Listing all files with Managed C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2) is possible and much easier than with unmanaged C++.

Managed C++ uses UNICODE. What is unicode? Shortly, it let's you use letters other than english. In your code you're not using unicode. That means if you happend to find a file which was, say, named with russian letters, you would not get its actual name.

In windows.h there are functions and variables unicode and non-unicode. Unicode version functions differ from non-unicode in name by having letter W at the end of their names in most cases. You can always find it by googling "*function or variable name* unicode". So you can use them by adding W to your function, for example FindFirstFileW instead of FileFirstFileA. Which your compiler is directing to by accessing FindFirstFile, but you could change that (make compiler seek unicode functions automatically) depeding on what program for compiling your code you're using. Google it.

To answer your question... this is how you edit your code:
all `string`s to `wstring`s

WIN32_FIND_DATA to WIN32_FIND_DATAW

`"/*.*"` to `L"/*.*"`

`Find...` functions to `Find...W`